# Flutter Firebase query array to change button color

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJTx3.png)

I would like to change the color of my arrow (Icon Button) after querying my firebase (likedby) array. Essentially my upvote / downvote system works by adding the user to a likedby/dislikedby array on the post and I want the arrow color to change if the users id is in the likedby or dislikedby arrays.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String currentUserId;

  const HomeScreen({Key key, this.currentUserId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Color(0xffff5722), title: Text("Feed")),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('The Laryngoscope')
              .snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                return Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 6, 15, 2),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 8.0,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text(document['title'] + "\n"),
                            subtitle: Text(document['authors']),
                          ),
                          Divider(),
                          ButtonBar(
                            children: [
                              Text(document['likes'].toString()),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.chevronUp,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    size: 30,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    articleRef.doc(document['title']).update({
                                      "dislikedby": FieldValue.arrayRemove(
                                          [widget.currentUserId]),
                                      "likedby": FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                                          [widget.currentUserId])
                                    });
                                    var documents = (await articleRef
                                        .doc(document['title'])
                                        .get());
                                    articleRef.doc(document['title']).update({
                                      "likes":
                                          (documents.data()['likedby'].length) -
                                              (documents
                                                  .data()['dislikedby']
                                                  .length)
                                    });
                                  }),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  FontAwesomeIcons.chevronDown,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  size: 30,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  articleRef.doc(document['title']).update({
                                    "likedby": FieldValue.arrayRemove(
                                        [widget.currentUserId]),
                                    "dislikedby": FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                                        [widget.currentUserId])
                                  });
                                  var documents = (await articleRef
                                      .doc(document['title'])
                                      .get());
                                  articleRef.doc(document['title']).update({
                                    "likes": (documents
                                            .data()['likedby']
                                            .length) -
                                        (documents.data()['dislikedby'].length)
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              OutlinedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.white, // background
                                  onPrimary: Color(0xffff5722), // foreground
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Text('Comment'),
                              ),
                              FloatingActionButton(
                                child: Icon(Icons.share),
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFF5722),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of what are you trying to achieve and What things have you already tried?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. I've just added a screenshot. Wanting to change the colour of the up and down arrows. I've tried setState but that changes all of the posts and I still haven't figured out how to change it based on an array query